# How can I find out what base table a custom table is pulling data from in SQL Developer or an application like DBeaver?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, datatables, schema

I have a bunch of data in a custom table entitled xxhiu.xxhiu_13mth_quantities. I need to know what base table/schema it's pulling data from in Oracle. Is there a trick to finding this out?

The package for the table states:

```
    BEGIN
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE xxhiu_13mth_quantities';
        commit;
           
            INSERT INTO xxhiu_13mth_quantities
               ( m1_sales, m2_sales, etc.)
            select * from 
            (select gl_seq
                     item_id,
                     organization_id,
                     etc.
              from xxhiu.xxhiu_13mth_stats)
            pivot (
               min ( fifo_avg ) as fifo_avg
               min ( fcst_avg ) as fcst_avg
               etc.
               for 
                 (gl_seq) in (01 as seq01
                             (10 as seq10
                             (11 as seq10
                             (12 as seq10
                              ...
                             (09 as seq09
            );

         l_count := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

         log_message (' Split up 13 Mth - Create math quant script Execution time in Mins: ' || ( (sys date -ldate)*1440, 2) );
         log_ouput (' Split up 13 Mth - Create math quant script Execution time in Mins: ' || ( (sys date -ldate)*1440, 2) );

         COMMIT;
END;
```

I need to know where the data, **m1_sales, m2_sales, etc.**, that is being inserted is coming from... I don't understand.. It's the only instance of the values in the whole package. Where is it coming from? At first I thought xxhiu_13mth_stats but that is a subquery for the other data, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is a subquery, where the top-level query is getting *all* of its data from. `xxhiu.xxhiu_13mth_stats` is the only table or view actually referenced in the query itself. That's your source.

Comment: I'm not clear what a 'custom table' is.

Comment: @pmdba Thanks! Even if none of the vales in the top-level query (i.e. m1_slales) appear in the subquery? How do they relate? Or do they not?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Basically what I am referring to is a table created from another (base) table. I am trying to figure out where this custom table is getting it's information from i.e. what base table it pulls data/columns from.